# Link item list to Carousel item

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I would like to link a list to another view (carousel layout), for example carousel item no. 2.
What should I put in this bracket?

```
                onItemDisclosure: function() {
                    [......]
                }
```

I want to achieve something like carousel.setActiveItem(x)
where x is my carousel content.

Comment: can u explain your question more ?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. What is displayed in your list (Could you post the model) ? What do you want to display in you Carousel ? Is there a relation between the tapped list item and the item in the carousel you want to display ?..

Comment: Hi, I'm using standard list (text). each item in the list has its own content, which I put in other view using carousel layout. here's the layout i want to achive http://postimage.org/image/45k02t8d5/

Comment: When I use Ext.ComponentManager.get('comp').setActiveItem(1); where 'comp' is my id for ext.tab.panel in in mainpanel, the view switch to carousel, but whichever list is clicked, it always point to carousel item 1. please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on your problem. May be this helps you.

**app.js**

```
        Ext.application({
            name: "FrontApp",

            models: ["mymodel"],
            stores: ["mystore"],
            controllers: ["FrontAppController"],
            views: ["front","carousel"],

            launch: function () {
                var frontView = {
                    xtype: "frontview"
                };
                var Carousel = {
                    xtype: "carousel"
                };

                Ext.Viewport.add([frontView,Carousel]);//views called by x-type

            }
        });
```

**front.js**

```
    Ext.define("FrontApp.view.front", {
    extend: "Ext.Panel",
    alias: "widget.frontview",

        config: {
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            fullscreen: true,
            scrollable: true,
            items: [

            {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    itemId: 'myList',
                    scrollable: false,
                    itemTpl: '{firstName}',
                    store: 'mystore51',
                    onItemDisclosure: true,

            }
            ],
            listeners:
            [

                {
                  delegate: "#myList",
                  event: "disclose",
                  fn: "onListDisclose"
                }

            ]
            },


            onListDisclose: function (list, record, target, index, evt, options) {
                console.log("calling carousel..");
                this.fireEvent("carouselCommand", this,record, target, index, evt, options);

            }

    });
```

**carousel.js**

```
 Ext.define('FrontApp.view.carousel', {
extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
xtype: 'carousel',

config: {

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'hello1'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'hello2'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'hello3'
        }
    ]
}

 });
```

**FrontAppController.js**

```
        Ext.define("FrontApp.controller.FrontAppController", {
        extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
            config: {
                refs: {   
                    frontView: "frontview", 
                    carouselView:"carousel"         
                 },
                control: {
                frontView: { 
                        carouselCommand: "onCarouselCommand"
                     }
                 }
            },
            // Transitions
            slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },
            slideRightTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' },


             onCarouselCommand: function (list, record, target, index, e, eOpts) {  
                console.log("onCarouselCommand");
                 var a=this.getCarouselView().setActiveItem(index); // setting the carousel item according to list index.
                 Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(a, this.slideLeftTransition);
            },
             // Base Class functions.
            launch: function () {
                this.callParent(arguments);
                console.log("launch");

            },
            init: function () {
                this.callParent(arguments);
                console.log("init");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hai, thanks much for your code. Anyhow, I've achieved this by using:                     onItemDisclosure: function(list, record, index) {
                       Ext.ComponentManager.get('comp').setActiveItem(1); //switch the view to carousel (my main content view)
 Ext.ComponentManager.get('content').setActiveItem(index); //set active item for carousel according to chosen list
                    }

Comment: @Sola Sawa From the next time please make sure to post your answer so that others will know that you have found the answer.

Comment: Yes i just refresh the page to post my answer, but it seems you're just ahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
onItemDisclosure: function(list, record, index) { 

//switch the view to carousel (my main content view) 
Ext.ComponentManager.get('comp').setActiveItem(1); 

//set active item for carousel according to chosen list 
Ext.ComponentManager.get('content').setActiveItem(index); 


}
```